# Can somebody explain why the following tiny powershell script behaves as it does?

Tags: powershell

Please, observe the following small powershell script (let us call it **a.ps1**):

```
param([switch]$WithFormat)

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe")
"-1-"
if ($WithFormat)
{
  @{a=$null} | Format-Table
}
"-2-"
$j = Start-Job { [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe") }
"-3-"
Wait-Job $j
"-4-"
Receive-Job $j
"-5-"
Remove-Job $j
```

Now, allow me to run it once without any arguments and then with the `-WithFormat` switch:

```
PS C:\tmp\1> .\a.ps1

GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
True   v4.0.30319     C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\MSBuild\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\MSBuild.exe
-1-
-2-
-3-

HasMoreData   : True
StatusMessage :
Location      : localhost
Command       :  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe")
JobStateInfo  : Completed
Finished      : System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
InstanceId    : b70f261c-50f7-455f-9169-f200df78dc9d
Id            : 168
Name          : Job168
ChildJobs     : {Job169}
PSBeginTime   : 3/28/2015 10:32:10 PM
PSEndTime     : 3/28/2015 10:32:12 PM
PSJobTypeName : BackgroundJob
Output        : {}
Error         : {}
Progress      : {}
Verbose       : {}
Debug         : {}
Warning       : {}
State         : Completed

-4-
True   v4.0.30319     C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\MSBuild\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\MSBuild.exe
-5-


PS C:\tmp\1> .\a.ps1 -WithFormat

GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
True   v4.0.30319     C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\MSBuild\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\MSBuild.exe
-1-



Name                           Value
----                           -----
a


-2-
-3-

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
170    Job170          BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost             [System.Reflection.As...
-4-

RunspaceId          : e1a6cac3-80f8-4dd8-8f8b-f687d1dcc8a0
CodeBase            : file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/MSBuild/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/MSBuild.exe
FullName            : MSBuild, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
EntryPoint          : Int32 Main()
DefinedTypes        : {Microsoft.Build.Shared.AssemblyNameComparer, Microsoft.Build.Shared.CollectionHelpers, Microsoft.Build.Shared.DirectoryGetFiles, Microsoft.Build.Shared.GetDirectories...}
Evidence            : {<System.Security.Policy.GacInstalled version="1"/>
                      , <StrongName version="1"
                      Key="002400000480000094000000060200000024000052534131000400000100010007D1FA57C4AED9F0A32E84AA0FAEFD0DE9E8FD6AEC8F87FB03766C834C99921EB23BE79AD9D5DCC1DD9AD236132102900B723CF980957FC4E177108FC607774F29E8320E92EA05ECE4E8
                      21C0A5EFE8F1645C4C0C93C1AB99285D622CAA652C1DFAD63D745D6F2DE5F17E5EAF0FC4963D261C8A12436518206DC093344D5AD293"
                      Name="MSBuild"
                      Version="4.0.0.0"/>
                      , <System.Security.Policy.Url version="1">
                      <Url>file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/MSBuild/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/MSBuild.exe</Url>
                      </System.Security.Policy.Url>
                      , <System.Security.Policy.Zone version="1">
                      <Zone>MyComputer</Zone>
                      </System.Security.Policy.Zone>
                      ...}
PermissionSet       : {}
SecurityRuleSet     : Level2
ManifestModule      : MSBuild.exe
ReflectionOnly      : False
Location            : C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\MSBuild\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\MSBuild.exe
ImageRuntimeVersion : v4.0.30319
GlobalAssemblyCache : True
HostContext         : 0
IsDynamic           : False
EscapedCodeBase     : file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/MSBuild/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/MSBuild.exe
ExportedTypes       : {Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp, Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp+ExitType}
IsFullyTrusted      : True
CustomAttributes    : {[System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute((System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute+DebuggingModes)2)], [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute()],
                      [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleToAttribute("MSBuild.Whidbey.Unittest, PublicKey=002400000480000094000000060200000024000052534131000400000100010007d1fa57c4aed9f0a32e84aa0faefd0de9e8fd6aec8f87fb03766c8
                      34c99921eb23be79ad9d5dcc1dd9ad236132102900b723cf980957fc4e177108fc607774f29e8320e92ea05ece4e821c0a5efe8f1645c4c0c93c1ab99285d622caa652c1dfad63d745d6f2de5f17e5eaf0fc4963d261c8a12436518206dc093344d5ad293")],
                      [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleToAttribute("MSBuild.Unittest, PublicKey=002400000480000094000000060200000024000052534131000400000100010007d1fa57c4aed9f0a32e84aa0faefd0de9e8fd6aec8f87fb03766c834c99921
                      eb23be79ad9d5dcc1dd9ad236132102900b723cf980957fc4e177108fc607774f29e8320e92ea05ece4e821c0a5efe8f1645c4c0c93c1ab99285d622caa652c1dfad63d745d6f2de5f17e5eaf0fc4963d261c8a12436518206dc093344d5ad293")]...}
Modules             : {MSBuild.exe}

-5-


PS C:\tmp\1>
```

For the life of me, I do not understand why the two runs produce such a drastically different output!

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Guys, notice the different output between the lines **-4-** and **-5-**. That output corresponds to the invocation of `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile` in the context of a background job and indicates that when I call the script with the `-WithFormat` flag a different security policy is used to load the assembly in the background job. That is the essence of the question - why on Earth would the use of `Format-Table` do that ?

**EDIT2**

Looks like there is a bug, but much more innocent and having nothing to do with the security policies. Powershell's notion of the default object rendering gets screwed up by calling `Format-Table` in my example.

**EDIT3**

Tried another script:

```
param([switch]$WithFormat,[switch]$WithJob)

$ScriptBlock = { dir "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" }
&$ScriptBlock
"-1-"
if ($WithFormat)
{
  @{a=$null} | Format-Table
}
"-2-"
if ($WithJob)
{
  $j = Start-Job $ScriptBlock
  "-3-"
  Wait-Job $j
  "-4-"
  Receive-Job $j
  "-5-"
  Remove-Job $j
}
else
{
  &$ScriptBlock
}
```

Running it with the different set of arguments reveals to me that there is a real mess with the default object formatting.

P.S.

```
PS C:\tmp\1> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      3.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34209
BuildVersion                   6.2.9200.17065
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2


PS C:\tmp\1> [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
6      2      9200   0

PS C:\tmp\1>
```

Comment: I use `Out-String` with `Format-*` cmdlets to avoid such differences in *mixed* output, i.e. in your case `@{a=$null} | Format-Table | Out-String`. The answer on the *Why* part is difficult, it's the details of PowerShell formatter.

Comment: You tried the suggestion and it did not work. The output is still different. Correct? I tried and it worked. The output is the same. Yes, perhaps I miss something or our environments are different.

Comment: As far as I can tell there has nothing to do with different security contexts. This all about how powershell formats output when there a multiple object types. Normally it looks for common properties to format everything into a table but if there aren't any, it just writes them in a list style. Using Format-Table seems to reset powershell's internal notion of what the currently outputted object type is so it displays starts to display properties in a table again.

Comment: The output from `Receive-Job` in your second example corresponds to piping it to `| Format-List *`, this is strictly a formatting issue

Comment: Guys, I am loading the assemblies identically. So why the output is different, but only if I called Format-Table before on an unrelated object?

Comment: @mikez sounds like a bug to me. A purely formatting bug is better than security policy thing that I suspected.

Comment: @RomanKuzmin - you are right, of course. But it is most unexpected, that calling `Format-Table` on an unrelated object produce such strange effect.

Comment: @RomanKuzmin - please, arrange your reply as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `Out-String` with `Format-*` cmdlets to avoid such differences in *mixed* output, i.e. in your case `@{a=$null} | Format-Table | Out-String`. The answer on the *Why* part is difficult, it's about internal details of PowerShell formatters.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with how PowerShell formats output when you have multiple object types in your output stream. It has nothing to do with jobs, assemblies, or security policy. PowerShell formats output by trying to display the same properties for all the objects in the output stream in a table. If you start mixing objects with different properties however, it just starts writing those objects properties in a list format. I don't know why, but PowerShell sort of "resets" when it hits a `Format-Table` and starts with next object as the current object type for formatting output. Perhaps this is a bug, I don't know.

We can demonstrate the behavior with a simpler example. Consider this input

```
gps idle; gsv winrm; gps idle
```

gives this output

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName  
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------  
      0       0        0          4     0               0 Idle

Status      : Stopped
Name        : winrm
DisplayName : Windows Remote Management (WS-Management)

      0       0        0          4     0               0 Idle
```

and this input

```
gps idle; @{a=0} | ft; gsv winrm; gps idle
```

gives this output

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
      0       0        0          4     0               0 Idle


Name                           Value
----                           -----
a                              0

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  winrm              Windows Remote Management (WS-Manag...

Id      : 0
Handles : 0
CPU     :
Name    : Idle
```

The output is very different between these two even though the only difference is an additional call to `Format-Table`.

In the first case PowerShell see a `Process` and starts formatting output for that. It gets a `ServiceController` object which does not have the same properties so it outputs it as a list. Then it gets another process object and continues the table (note how there are no headers).

In the second case, calling `Format-Table` seems to "reset" the current object PowerShell is considering as the output. When it receives the second Process object, it does not have the same properties as the `ServiceController` so it just displays it in a list format.

Blasting everything to `Out-String` or `Format-Table` will certainly work if your goal is format the output in a certain way, but that might not be solution if you want to be able to work with output as objects.